# Get Current running page in WPF Frame Navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a simple WPF application which is having App.xaml and then MainWindow.xaml. 
I am using a Frame in the MainWindow to navigate from one page to another using a TreeView.

MainWindow

Frame:

```
    <Frame Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="contentFrame" 
        NavigationUIVisibility="Visible" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" />
```

TreeView:

```
        <TreeViewItem Header="Employee" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsEnabled="True">
            <TreeViewItem Header= "Employee Details" Selected="TreeViewItemEmployee_Selected"/>
        </TreeViewItem>
```

in .Cs File:

```
    private void TreeViewItemEmployee_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       EmployeePage objEmployeePage  = new EmployeePage ();
        contentFrame.Navigate(objEmployeePage);
    }
```

User can navigate to Page 1 to Page 2 and so on......

Now I have to find out which page is currently being loaded in frame i.e which page user is currently viewing.

I tried Navigated="Navigation_Selected" property of frame and added below in .CS file but it doesn't work and throw Object reference error.

```
    private void NavigationWindow_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(contentFrame.CurrentSource.ToString());
    }
```

Any help on this ?

Comment: If you add a breakpoint on the line where you show the messagebox and then hover over contentFrame, is contentFrame null?

Comment: @TheRedLou Yes contentframe.CurrentSource is null. Pls see the comment below.

Comment: Also in my App.xaml i have set StartupUri as a Login.xaml and when login is successful i am doint this :                         MainWindow objMainWindow = new MainWindow();
                        objMainWindow.Show();
                        Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();